# using shell_exec to call a perl script from php

Tags: php

I am having an issue with executing a perl script from php using the shell_exec() function.

This is what I have tried (and it has worked before).

```
$perl = shell_exec("/usr/bin/perl cbh_script_clean.pl");
echo ($perl);
```

This will not work as $perl does not contain anything after this is executed.

Thoughts?

All help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/bin/perl cbh_script_clean.pl` straight from the command line?

Comment: But what happens? What do you see on the screen after you run the command?

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` after the command. Chances are the pathname to the perl script is just wrong. Also have a look into the error.log, which otherwise contains the according message.

Comment: @webbie: the script is run fully.  it successfully runs the script

Comment: @mario: what exactly does that do?

Comment: ahhhh it tells me there is a permissions error.  i was creating 2 logs in order to troubleshoot with the Net::Telnet:Cisco module and i didnt have them set for full permissions

Comment: What it does is: telling you that there was a permissions error. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll make that an answer then.

You can often append `2>&1` to redirect the **stderr** output to the normal **stdout** stream. This way you receive any error messages in the PHP variable. (Otherwise they will get lost with `system`/`exec`/`shell_exec`, which is why people sometimes use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) with explicit pipes instead).

```
$perl = shell_exec("/usr/bin/perl cbh_script_clean.pl 2>&1");
echo ($perl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

$perl = shell_exec("/usr/bin/perl cbh_script_clean.pl 2>/dev/null >/dev/null &");
echo ($perl);